# Cosa vuol dire "incartato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> I tavolini all'aperto con le coppie apparecchiate, offrivano indizi di una Spagna vogliosa di mode: e seguendo i dettami delle riviste era facile vedere una lei con i torreggianti capelli scolpiti dalla lacca, e un lui **incartato** in un principe di Galles.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "incartato" in questo testo? I dizionari che ho consultato spiegano che è il participio passato di "incartare" e quindi significa avvolto, coperto, rivestito di carta, ma questo non sembra avere molto senso nel brano citato.

Comment: C'è effettivamente quella virgola fra il soggetto e il verbo?

Comment: @DaG: Hai ragione: non ci dovrebbe essere, ma è così come appare nel libro.

Comment: @dag quella virgola infastidisce anche me. Se almeno ce ne fosse una dopo "all'aperto"! Meglio ancora se non ce ne fosse nessuna.

Comment: Va bene, @DaG e linuxfan: forse non è un testo perfetto. A me piace, comunque. Tenete anche conto che è stato pubblicato da una piccola casa editrice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direi che significhi semplicemente che gli uomini seduti ai tavolini sono appunto “avvolti”, “impacchettati” ognuno nel suo principe di Galles (inteso per metonimia come abito fatto dell'[omonimo tessuto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/principe/)), per esprimere forse che non lo indossano con eleganza e spontaneità ma in modo goffo, rigido.

Comment: Infatti, il [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000637.jpg) spiega che in Toscana si usa "incartato" per definire un tessuto che è "rigido come carta".